# ionic cordova fcm notifications error with firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, npm, firebase-notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

i want to implement the notifications feature by firebase on my ionic application
so after proceeding with the following command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
```

and adding the google-services.json to the main folder of my ionic project I am facing the following error with no success to solve it

```
(node:15256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or 
buffer, not object

(node:15256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i found on google that firebase has several bugs on it's latest version which is 4.8.2 and 4.8.1 so as well i did a downgrade to firebase 4.8.0.

as well i tried the npm install and npm cache verify and i checked that i have the same package name in my project and firebase with no success to solve it.